# After migrate:delta without -r if go to some places such Catalog, Invoices system show "loading"

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, delta-migration

After run a `migrate:delta` when go to Catalog > Inventory > Products for example, dashboard show a spinner permanent.

Show in others areas.
Shop is in developer mode, clean caches.

On logs /var/log don't see any error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show the error, please run the the command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Site is already in developer mode. I see on ask ** Shop is in developer mode**